# How to get files list of one folder only at the Rollup.js compile time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, rollupjs

I would like to achieve the following, only at the **Rollup.js compile time**:

1. Get files list of the `./src/markdown-files/` folder.
2. Store this files list in a global variable.
3. Use this global variable on DEV and PROD side.

I use Svelte v3.23.2 and Rollup.js v2.15.0.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include code at the start of a bundle (inside wrapper) by using `output.intro`.

```js
const markdownFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/markdown-files/");
export default {
    output: {
        intro: `const MARKDOWN_FILES = ${JSON.stringify(markdownFiles)};`
    }
}
```

**There is no way to check if the script is being run to 'compile'**, as the config file returns nothing more than a plain object and has no globals but for imports.

Comment: Many thanks   For others like me, here is the doc: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputintrooutputoutro

Comment: Another way: https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-your-svelte-js-app